# Looping through different files/subdirectories with bash

Tags: bash, loops

I'm trying to convert a cshell script into a bash one. To compile some files in different subdirectories, it uses foreach

```
 cd $BLDSRCDIR
 foreach file ( $flist )
    $myCC -c $myCFLAGS $file.c -o $BLDDIR/$file.o
 end for
```

Because bash doesn't have foreach, I tried:

```
 for file [ $flist ] in
 do
    $myCC -c $myCFLAGS $file.c -o $BLDDIR/$file.o
 done
```

But this syntax is not correct ( `syntax error near unexpected token ['` ). There is probably more than one solution but I was wondering about a concise way to loop through (and compile) all files in the different subdirectories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
for file in $flist ; do
    "$myCC" -c $myCFLAGS "$file.c" -o "$BLDDIR/$file.o"
done
```

But using arrays would be cleaner.

```sh
for file in "${flist[@]}" ; do
    "$myCC" -c "${myCFLAGS[@]}" "$file.c" -o "$BLDDIR/$file.o"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the items to be looped over aren't enclosed in any punctuation; if you supply them literally, it looks like this:

```
for file in file1 file2 file3; do
  ...
done
```

Second, how are you populating the variable `flist`? Ideally, it should be an array, which can be created with literal values like this:

```
flist=(file1 file2 file3...)
```

but if you're getting it as the output of some other command then It takes a bit more work to turn that into an array.

You would loop over such an array like this:

```
for file in "${flist[@]}"; do
...
done
```

You could just have `flist` be a string of filenames and do `for file in $flist; do` (note lack of quotes), but that breaks if any of the filenames contain whitespace etc.

Comment: The content of flist is directly declared in a previous statement (it's a long script). Thanks.

Comment: If it's a list in csh ( `set flist=(name1 name2 name3)` ) then the equivalent bash ( `flist=(name1 name2 name3)` ) gets you an array which you need to use the `"${flist[@]}"` syntax to loop over.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is pretty simple, the syntax for a for loop in bash is:

```
for file in [ $flist ]
do
    $myCC -c $myCFLAGS $file.c -o $BLDDIR/$file.o
done
```

However the next problem is going to be bash does not have a -c option, and I'm not familiar with c shell so I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do here.

Hope this helps, but if you need additional assistance, just let me know what specifically you're trying to do with each file and I can give you an example in bash

Comment: The -c flag is for the compiler but I now understand what I was doing wrong. Thanks.